# Manually removing all of LogMeIn

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which removes LogMeIn (or any program where you search by name) from add/remove programs.

This works perfectly however I would like to remove all instances of LMI, meaning any version that has been installed locally via plug-ins etc.

The only way I thought of doing this was to delete the respective registry entries and app data - however querying the HKEY_USERS hive instead of HKCU hive is proving troublesome.

Anyone had to do something similar, where they have a search term in registry they want to blitz off? 
I have tried the mapping HKEY_USERS to a PS-Drive to query but just cant get the terminology right.

```
function ForceUninstall {
Stop-Process -processname LMIGuardian*
Stop-Process -processname LogMeIn*
Stop-Process -processname LogMeInSystray*
Stop-Process -processname ramaint*


$null = New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKEY_USERS -Root HKEY_USERS
cd HKEY_USERS:/
$objects = get-childItem HKEY_USERS:\  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

 foreach ($object in $objects){
 $testpath = "$($object.name)\Software\LogMeIn"

$testpath =  $testpath -replace [Regex]::Escape("HKEY_USERS\"),'HKEY_USERS:\'
$testpath2 = "$($object.name)\Software\LogMeIn Ignition"
$testpath2 = $testpath2 -replace [Regex]::Escape("HKEY_USERS\"),'HKEY_USERS:\'
If (test-path $testpath) {
 $PathsToDelete += $testpath 
 }

 If (test-path $testpath2) {
$PathsToDelete += $testpath2 
 }

}
  foreach ($Path in  $PathsToDelete){
 write-host "removing $path"
 (Get-ChildItem $Path).PsPath |Remove-Item -Recurse
 "Deleted registry key"
 }


 $LocalPaths = @("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LMIInfo",
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\SOFTWARE\LogMeIn"
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LMIMaint",
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LMImirr",
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LMIRfsClientNP",
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LMIRfsDriver",
        "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\System\Current Control Set\Services\LogMeIn")



$Location = New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -Root HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
cd HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:/
 foreach ($Path in  $LocalPaths){
 write-host "removing $path"
 (Get-ChildItem $Path).PsPath |Remove-Item -Recurse
 "Deleted registry key"
 }

 Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "LogMeIn GUI"
write-host "removed LogMeIn GUI file"

 }
```

Comment: "I've tried ... but just cant get the terminology right" - at least show us what you've tried :-)

Comment: You're very likely to get errors on the attempts to access keys under HKU; that particular hive is handled _by Windows_ quite differently from HKLM. I'd advise allowing the HKU accesses to throw errors unless/until you're fully conversant with how that hive is handled.

Comment: The HKEY_USERS drive only shows currently active users.  You'd need to load the .dat registries of all users to do what you're trying to accomplish which may cause issues with them signing in concurrently with your task

Comment: I thought HKEY_USERS shows all user containers in the a machine, not HKCU which shows the current logged in session?

Comment: @VKrishan That is incorrect.  It shows currently loaded users (remote sessions, system users, etc.).  Here's a [useful article](https://www.pdq.com/blog/modifying-the-registry-users-powershell/) that should accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.